# Dados de uma DataGridView configurada em outra Form

Tags: c#, datagridview

Eu tenho o **Form1** que possui uma **dataGridView** e um **botão** para adicionar conteúdos nessa Grid. Ao selecionar esse botão, eu chamo o **Form2** que possui 2 **TextBox** e um **ComboBox** para preencher o Nome, Diretório e Formato (por exemplo), além de um **botão** OK para adicionar a linha a **dataGridView** na **Form1**.

Quando eu voltar na **Form1**, o **dataGridView** precisa estar mostrando o conteúdo inserido. O que acontece é que a minha Grid possui três colunas: Nome, Formato e um **button column** para, ao clicar nele, recarregar aquela tela do Form2 com as informações previamente preenchidas novamente carregadas em cada campo para poder alterar ou somente consultar.

Primeiramente tentei criar uma função para adicionar as linhas a minha Grid por parametros, como mostra o código abaixo:

Form 1

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void AddRows(string nome, string path)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(nome, path);
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

Form 2

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nome = txt_nome.Text;
    var path = txt_path.Text;

    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.AddRows(nome, path);
}
```

Entretanto, acabou não funcionando, não mostrando nada na Grid. Então eu pensei em criar uma classe com um método nome, path e formato (**get** e **set** para cada um) para guardar tudo em uma lista de objetos (acho que é isso, me perdoem se estiver errado pois sou iniciante). Ou então guardar em um **DataSet**. Mas aí eu pensei, eu instancio a classe na minha **Form2** e passo os valores preenchidos nos campos, mas e aí, o que eu faço na minha **Form1**?

Acho que está tudo muito confuso, agradeceria se alguém pudesse explicar um método mais claro de resolver essa situação e por favor, sejam bem específicos pois sou iniciante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não funciona se você cria outra instância do `Form1` dentro do `Form2`. Você teria que passar a instância que está aberta do `Form1` ou fazer a inserção diretamente nele.

O mais simples é:

> Ao clicar no OK, o Form2 irá retornar DialogResult.OK e terá as propriedades `TxtNome` e `TxtPath` preenchido com os valores necessários.

```
public string TxtNome {get;set;}
public string TxtPath {get;set;}

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txt_nome.Text = this.TxtNome;
   txt_path.Text = this.TxtPath;
}

private void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TxtNome = txt_nome.Text;
    this.TxtPath = txt_path.Text;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;    
}
```

> Agora no `Form1`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Form2 form = new Form2();
      if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          AddRows(form.TxtNome, form.TxtPath);
      }
      //Se não retornar OK (um botão cancelar por exemplo) não faz nada

}    


private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >=0 && !dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();

        form.TxtNome = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        form.TxtPath = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            EditRow(e.RowIndex, form.TxtNome, form.TxtPath);
        }
    }
}
public void AddRows(string nome, string path)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(nome, path);
    dataGridView2.Update();
}
public void EditRow(int idx, string nome, string path)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows[idx].Cells[0].Value = nome;
    dataGridView2.Rows[idx].Cells[1].Value = path;
}
```

Se quiser a parte de edição dos itens, posta seu código do botão dentro da datagridview que eu te ajudo com ele também.

Comment: Incrível, funcionou direitinho! Eu estava pensando, eu vou ter mais dados nessa tela de edição, então em vez de chamar a tela de consulta com um botão, eu poderia chamar com um duplo clique. Você tem alguma ideia sobre isso?

Comment: fiz as funções, e atualizei a resposta. veja se te ajuda e não se esqueça de marcar como resposta

Comment: Eu não sei o que está acontecendo pois ele pega os valores certos na hora que eu edito, mas depois aparece errado na grid.

Comment: aonde tem `Cells[0]` e `Cells[1]` você pode mudar o index dessas células ou colocar o nome das colunas. Ex: `Cells[ColumnPath.Name]`

Comment: Desculpe, falta de atenção! Coloquei duas repetidas pois adicionei mais! Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mesmo!!!

Comment: sem problemas =]